# Preparing two images with different dimensions to use in Agisoft PhotoScan

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, erdas-imagine, digital-image-processing

I have two aerial photos that are flowed over the national forest. The photos were scanned by a contractor and they came in various dimensions for each photos.

The one I have had smaller dimension and the other had bigger dimension.

How do I make the smaller image bigger dimension so I can use it to perform overlay each other with Agisoft PhotoScan?

Both image I have do not have no coordinate and projection.

I have ERDAS Imagine 2018 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, and ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2 here on my computer.

Comment: are the spatial extents the same? what about the pixel sizes?

Comment: Both are different in extent and pixel sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out how to get the image's dimensions to work.... The tricking part is if I remember right was to use the export raster's settings in ArcGIS Pro.

So in ArcGIS Pro, you just bring in the smaller image to the map and right click to export raster or use the export to different raster in the toolbox.

Get the dimensions numbers from the large image and then put that number to the export raster settings in the raster size before you run it.

In order to use the new image in Agisoft Photoscan/Metashape, I had to change the 16 bit to 8 bit in ERDAS Imagine.

Agisoft Metashape/PhotoScan only can read in 8 bits in order to use it to perform co-registration/co-registration there.